# Dynamic iCal generator outside/inside wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, calendar, outside-wordpress

So following on from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1463480/1086990 I was wondering how exactly it would work integrating it into Wordpress.

I have a custom post type setup, and so far I have tried both linking to a "ical.php" with the above link code (and changing the title into `the_title()` and the dates into GMT versions of my `date(..)` code). None work, because it can find the `get_post_custom_values()` which is obvious since not in WP loop, or a WP associated file.

Next I tried adding the `headers` into the `header.php` WP file, and adding a `if(is_singular("event"))`, but the headers auto download. If I can stop the auto download then I'm ace, otherwise I come here for help!

Is there any reasonable way that is dynamically able to be populated via WP and **only** download when the link is clicked, not automatically?

*I would host everything, but the events are going to be so often, that making and hosting would be a waste* **also** is there maybe a href generator like Google Calendar that would automatically work?

---

**EDIT (My working code):**

**Custom Taxonomy Loop**

```
<form action="<?php echo get_feed_link('calendar-event'); ?>" method="post">
    <input hidden="hidden" name="eventID" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <button title="Add to iCal" type="submit" name="iCalForm">iCal</button>
</form>
```

**iCal.php**
I included this into the `functions.php` via a `require()`.

```
<?php //Event ICAL feed
class SH_Event_ICAL_Export  {

    public function load() { add_feed('calendar-event', array(__CLASS__,'export_events')); }

    // Creates an ICAL file of events in the database
    public function export_events(){ 

        //Give the iCal export a filename
        $filename = urlencode( 'event-ical-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.ics' );

        //Collect output 
        ob_start();

        // File header
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
        header("Content-type: text/calendar");
        header("Pragma: 0");
        header("Expires: 0");
?>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?> //NONSGML Events //EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:<?php echo get_bloginfo('name');?>: Events
<?php // Query for events

    if(isset($_POST['iCalForm'])) {
        $post_ID = $_POST['eventID'];
        $events = new WP_Query(array(
            'p' => $post_ID,
            'post_type' => 'event'  //Or whatever the name of your post type is
        ));

    if($events->have_posts()) : while($events->have_posts()) : $events->the_post();
        $uid = get_the_ID(); // Universal unique ID
        $dtstamp = date_i18n('Ymd\THis\Z',time(), true); // Date stamp for now.
        $created_date = get_post_time('Ymd\THis\Z', true, get_the_ID() ); // Time event created
        // Other pieces of "get_post_custom_values()" that make up for the StartDate, EndDate, EventOrganiser, Location, etc.
        // I also had a DeadlineDate which I included into the BEGIN:VALARM
        // Other notes I found while trying to figure this out was for All-Day events, you just need the date("Ymd"), assuming that Apple iCal is your main focus, and not Outlook, or others which I haven't tested :]
?>
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:<?php echo $created_date;?>

UID:<?php echo $uid;?>

DTEND;VALUE=DATE:<?php echo $end_date; ?>

TRANSP:OPAQUE
SUMMARY:<?php echo $organiser; ?>

DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:<?php echo $start_date ; ?>

DTSTAMP:<?php echo $dtstamp;?>

LOCATION:<?php echo $location;?>

ORGANIZER:<?php echo $organiser;?>

URL;VALUE=URI:<?php echo "http://".$url; ?>

BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:<?php echo $dLine; ?>

DESCRIPTION:Closing submission day of films for <?php echo $organiser; ?>! Enter quickly!
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
<?php endwhile; endif; } ?>
END:VCALENDAR
<?php //Collect output and echo 
    $eventsical = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $eventsical;
    exit();
    }   

} // end class
SH_Event_ICAL_Export::load();
?>
```

Hope this serves well to whoever needs it, as it is a fantastic piece of work, so again thanks Stephen Harris who helped more than the question, and additionally without suggesting I use his plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use WordPress' *feeds*. You can create your own feed with [`add_feed`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed). You specify a callback and this callback is responsible for displaying the output.

### Creating a feed

```
add_feed('my-events','wpse56187_ical_cb');
```

`wpse56187_ical_cb` is that responsible for getting the events (use `WP_Query`), looping through them and printing the ICAL fields.

### Downloading the ICAL file

If your feed is 'my-events', then the ical file can then be downloaded by going to:

```
www.yoursite.com?feed=my-events
www.yoursite.com/feed/my-events //If you have pretty permalinks
```

The link to the feed can be obtained by [`get_feed_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_feed_link/). So if you wanted to create a link to you event's feed in your template:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_feed_link('my-events'); ?>" > Click here for ical file </a>
```

### Example

I've omitted the details of filling in the event details in ICAL format (how you do this will depend on how you've stored the details).

The following class implements the above method and creates a feed called 'my-events'. You will need to make sure the details are formatted correctly and are valid (see [this site](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/))

*Please note, I've not tested the following so there may be syntax errors*

```
<?php
/**
 * Event ICAL feed
 */
class SH_Event_ICAL_Export  {

    public function load(){
        add_feed('my-events', array(__CLASS__,'export_events'));
    }

   /**
    * Creates an ICAL file of events in the database
    *  @param string filename - the name of the file to be created
    *  @param string filetype - the type of the file ('text/calendar')
    */ 
    public function export_events( ){ 

    //Give the ICAL a filename
    $filename = urlencode( 'event-ical-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.ics' );

    //Collect output 
    ob_start();

    // File header
    header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename );
    header('Content-type: text/calendar');
    header("Pragma: 0");
    header("Expires: 0");
?>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//<?php  get_bloginfo('name'); ?>//NONSGML Events //EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:<?php echo get_bloginfo('name');?> - Events

<?php
  
    // Query for events
    $events = WP_Query(array(
         'post_type'=>'event' //Or whatever the name of your post type is
         'posts_per_page'=>-1 //Get all events
          ...
    ));

    if( $events->have_posts() ):
        while( $events->have_posts() ): $events->the_post();
            $uid=''; //Universal unique ID
            $dtstamp=date_i18n('Ymd\THis\Z',time(), true); //date stamp for now.
            $created_date=get_post_time('Ymd\THis\Z', true, get_the_ID() ); //time event created
            $start_date=""//event start date
            $end_date=""//event end date
            $reoccurrence_rule=false//event reoccurrence rule.
            $location=''//event location
            $organiser=''//event organiser
?>
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:<?php echo $uid;?>

DTSTAMP:<?php echo $dtstamp;?>

CREATED:<?php echo $created_date;?>

DTSTART:<?php echo $start_date ; ?>

DTEND:<?php echo $end_date; ?>

<?php if ($reoccurrence_rule):?>
RRULE:<?php echo $reoccurrence_rule;?>

<?php endif;?>

LOCATION: <?php echo $location;?>

ORGANIZER: <?php $organiser;?>

END:VEVENT
<?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
END:VCALENDAR
<?php

    //Collect output and echo 
    $eventsical = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $eventsical;
    exit();
    }   

} // end class
SH_Event_ICAL_Export::load();
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you! I understand what you're doing, and its making things tonnes easier, but unfortunately I'm not familiar with PHP Classes, and the placement of that code.
Under "Creating A Feed" should I add `add_feed('my-events','wpse56187_ical_cb');` directly to the functions.php, or should it be called elsewhere? This because, when I call `<a href="<?php echo get_feed_link('my-events'); ?>" > Click here for ical file </a>` it directs to a 404 page, not the content.

Comment: Also the mass chunk of code, do I make that another file (i.e. `ical.php`) and include/require it in the single-event.php (single for taxonomy)? And with the `WP_Query` do I only call the custom data, because I usually use `get_post_custom_values()` for that, or should it be the whole shebang (post_type, offset,paged,etc.)?
Sorry if that's a lot, but yeah I tried your example, and I'm no novice, nor expert, but couldn't get it going?

Comment: Sorry, I omitted `SH_Event_ICAL_Export::load()` from the very bottom (will edit answer now). The code should work 'as is' once you've filled in the details for the `WP_Query` (except for maybe syntax errors). So the above chunk can go wholesale into functions.php - though it should really be a plug-in.

Comment: The `WP_Query` should query for your event post type. Inside the loop, set the the variables with the appropriate data (see comments). How you do that depends on where you store the data - presumably you're storing in post meta?

Comment: Yep that was all great! But note for any other future readers, make sure you save your permalinks if you've been messing with them or else the 404 error page will show up (the code above is solid other than syntax errors)!
On other notes, would've used your plugin if I didn't already customise my own event taxonomy :] True champ!

Comment: Good call on flushing the rewrite rules! Re. my plug-in, events are just a custom post type so you can use your own event taxonomy and register it with the plug-in's event post type using [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) :). Feel free to make corrections to the answer (if you're allowed to?).

Comment: One last thing, is there a way to only call the details from that exact page the call is made from, or do I have to get everything in the feed?

Comment: Not sure I understand you... what details from what page? The feed can contain as many/as few events as you like by just altering the `WP_Query`.

Comment: So I have the call for `get_feed_link("XXXXXXXXX")` in the event page loop. When I press the link, it downloads the entire taxonomy of events rather than that specific page. I have tried getting the ID via `get_the_ID()` in the WP_Query, but since its not an internal part of the loop, it returns null.
Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I wanted only the "single" event d/l. Also if it is via the get_feed_link, I can't find any documentation on it

Comment: Never mind. I changed the the `<a href="<?php echo get_feed_link('my-events'); ?>" > Click here for ical file </a>` to be a form, and input with the hidden value of the postID. In the iCal.php file with your code, I made the check for isset, and set a variable for the input(postID) and set that for the post in the loop of the WP_Query. I knew what I wanted, but was unsure at first!
I will update my OP with the code I used :] Again thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different version than Stephen's.
I integrated some things and changed others.

Code is tested and works fine, as I'm using it in a project.

```
function add_calendar_feed(){
    add_feed('calendar', 'export_events');
    // Only uncomment these 2 lines the first time
    /*global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules( false );*/
}
add_action('init', 'add_calendar_feed');

function export_events(){

   // Helper - Get the right time format, use this function or date_i18n('Ymd\THis\Z', $yourtimehere, true);
   /*function dateToCal($timestamp) {
       return date('Ymd\THis\Z', $timestamp);
   }*/
   // Helper - Escapes a string of characters
   function escapeString($string) {
       return preg_replace('/([\,;])/','\\\$1', $string);
   }
   // Helper - Cut it
   function shorter_version($string, $lenght) {
        if (strlen($string) >= $lenght) {
            return substr($string, 0, $lenght);
        } else {
            return $string;
        }
   }

    // Query the event
    $the_event = new WP_Query(array(
        'p' => $_REQUEST['id'],
        'post_type' => 'any',
    ));

    if($the_event->have_posts()) :

        while($the_event->have_posts()) : $the_event->the_post();

        $timestamp = date_i18n('Ymd\THis\Z',time(), true);
        $uid = get_the_ID();
        $created_date = get_post_time('Ymd\THis\Z', true, $uid ); // post creation
        $start_date = date_i18n('Ymd\THis\Z',time(), true); // EDIT THIS WITH START DATE VALUE
        $end_date = date_i18n('Ymd\THis\Z',time(), true); // EDIT THIS WITH END DATE VALUE
        $deadline = date_i18n('Ymd\THis\Z',time()-24, true); // deadline in BEGIN:VALARM
        $organiser = get_bloginfo('name'); // YOUR NAME OR SOME VALUE
        $address = ''; // EDIT THIS WITH SOME VALUE
        $url = get_the_permalink();
        $summary = get_the_excerpt();
        $content = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', get_the_content())); // removes newlines and double spaces

        //Give the iCal export a filename
        $filename = urlencode( get_the_title().'-ical-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.ics' );
        $eol = "\r\n";

        //Collect output
        ob_start();

        // File header
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
        header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
        header("Pragma: 0");
        header("Expires: 0");
?>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?> //NONSGML Events //EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:<?php echo get_bloginfo('name');?>
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:<?php echo $created_date.$eol;?>
UID:<?php echo $uid.$eol;?>
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:<?php echo $end_date.$eol; ?>
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:<?php echo $start_date.$eol; ?>
DTSTAMP:<?php echo $timestamp.$eol; ?>
LOCATION:<?php echo escapeString($address).$eol; ?>
DESCRIPTION:<?php echo shorter_version($content,70).$eol; ?>
SUMMARY:<?php echo escapeString(get_the_title()).$eol; ?>
ORGANIZER:<?php echo escapeString($organiser).$eol;?>
URL;VALUE=URI:<?php echo escapeString($url).$eol; ?>
TRANSP:OPAQUE
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:<?php echo $deadline.$eol; ?>
DESCRIPTION:Fine / Scadenza di <?php echo escapeString(get_the_title()); echo $eol; ?>
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
<?php
        endwhile;
?>
END:VCALENDAR
<?php
        //Collect output and echo
        $eventsical = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        echo $eventsical;
        exit();

    endif;

}
?>
```

Then in your theme, use this link:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_feed_link('calendar'); ?>?id=<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">Get the ical file </a>
```

Made a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/Jany-M/af50d5c4a0eec2692734d76383ed4dd8) out of it (forked), with some more info.

Comment: The gist is fine, but independently from WPSE. You should add this here, include all hints, comments to the source. That is a better way to create solid answers also for readers in the future.

Comment: Sure I understand. I wanted to leave the code "ready to use", without too much info in between. The extra info isnt necessary really, but I did leave the really important comments in here.